# How to schedule send message in Quickblox android?

Tags: android, quickblox

I want to create scheduled send message function in my chat application.

Does Quickblox Android support to it?

Comment: this is as on you if you can develop it.

Answer (score 2):

Basically there are 2 possible options:

1.You can do this kind of thing via hidden (system) XMPP message properties but you’ll need to implement custom handling for such messages on client-side (basicall message will be sent to a user but he will be unable to receive it till the particular date).

2.There is no client-side support for delayed scheduled XMPP messages, but there is such feature available for Push Notification messages. So it can be done via Push Notification messages as well.